# How to Include PHP Variable in XML String

Tags: php, xml, string

I'm trying to include a PHP variable inside an XML string. It doesn't seem to be working, can someone see what's wrong with it.

```
// Construct contact data in XML format
$data = <<<STRING
<contact>
<Group_Tag name="Contact Information">
<field name="First Name">$firstname</field>
<field name="Last Name">$lastname</field>
<field name="Email">$email</field>
</Group_Tag>
</contact>
<Group_Tag name="Sequences and Tags">
<field name="Contact Tags">Test</field>
<field name="Sequences">*/*3*/*8*/*</field>
</Group_Tag>
</contact>
STRING;

$data = urlencode(urlencode($data));
```

Comment: not working **HOW**?

Comment: Seems to be working just fine: http://codepad.org/e1fc29Yl. Maybe provide some more specific context, verify the values of `$firstname`, `$lastname`, etc...

Comment: See your XML its not in correct format.Remove </contact> tag from middle.

Answer (score 1):

This will work!!

```
<contact>
 <Group_Tag name="Contact Information">
  <field name="First Name">'. $firstname.'</field>
  <field name="Last Name">'. $lastname.'</field>
  <field name="Email">'. $email.'</field>
 </Group_Tag>
</contact>
```

In certain cases, where your variable contains characters like "&" and "<" adding CDATA tags before and after the variable is needed, because they break the XML. In your case the $projectid seems to be an id (int), but maybe your going to use more variable's in your script which contain those characters, be aware of the importance of CDATA tags in such cases.
Example:

```
<field name="First Name"><![CDATA['. $firstname.']]></field>
```

Comment: Is there a way to call a function within the string? `$response->getSomething($arguments)`

Comment: Brackets work for calling a function within the string. `{$response->getSomething($arguments)}`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$data = "
 <contact>
    <Group_Tag name=\"Contact Information\">
    <field name=\"First Name\">$firstname</field>
    <field name=\"Last Name\">$lastname</field>
    <field name=\"Email\">$email</field>
    </Group_Tag>
    </contact>
    <Group_Tag name=\"Sequences and Tags\">
    <field name=\"Contact Tags\">Test</field>
    <field name=\"Sequences\">*/*3*/*8*/*</field>
    </Group_Tag>
  </contact>
";

echo $data;
```

Comment: and this is a solution... HOW? If OP's heredoc isn't working, then switching to a multi-line string isn't going to help either.